# Why writing a text file in C does not gives me expected results?

Tags: c

I am trying to do several exercises to understand the difference between write text and binary files on C, and when looking at results with an hexdump utility I am finding unexpected results.  Can you please help me to understand the reason ?

Particularly, I am trying the following code for writing a text file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *ptr_myfile;
    char c = 'a';
    int numero = 12345;

    ptr_myfile = fopen("test.txt","w");

    if (!ptr_myfile){
        printf("Unable to open file!");
        return 1;
    }

    fwrite(&c, sizeof(char), 1, ptr_myfile);
    fwrite(&numero, sizeof(int), 1, ptr_myfile);

    fclose(ptr_myfile);

    return 0;
}
```

When doing a "cat test.txt" I found that the contents of the file are:

> cat test.txt
>
> a90

Can not understand how 12345 was converted to 90.

Moreover If I do a

```
hexdump test.txt

0000000 3961 0030 0000
0000005
```

On that case, I am findig a first byte written with the value 39.  Why ?  Second value (61) already matches the ascii value fo 'a''  (61 hex = 97 dec = 'a' ascii code),  but can not find a logical explanation for the rest of the bits.

If I change the writing mode to binary file, modifying the line

```
ptr_myfile=fopen("test.txt","w")  by ptr_myfile=fopen("test.txt","wb")
```

I do not see any change on behavior on the written contents of the file.

Comment: With `fwrite` you write the raw binary data of the values, not their text representations. And for an `int` that's usually four bytes of data.

Comment: Hint, 12345 in hex is 3039.

Comment: Use `hexdump -C`, it should be less confusing

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude,  so, with fwrite I am always writing on binary, no matter on which mode I did the open of the file ?  Are you saying that I am treating the file as binary insted of text ? Why the "fopen" mode is ignored ?

Comment: Yes that's correct. The decimal value `12345` will be written as the four bytes `0x00003039`. If you want to write text, use e.g. `fprintf` like `fprintf(ptr_myfile, "%c%d", c, numero)`

Comment: "Why the "fopen" mode is ignored?" Read about (don't guess, read) what fopen mode actually means.

Comment: @n.m.  thks, from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43777913/the-difference-in-file-access-mode-w-and-wb  I understand that the only difference is how a few characters (ie, end of line, are converted, either on \r\n in text mode or just \n in binary), but it has not effect on writring raw or text... (I was misunderstanding that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contents of the file `test.txt` is:

```
$ hexdump -C test.txt

00000000  61 39 30 00 00                                    |a90..|
00000005
```

The first byte `61` is `'a'` and the bytes after that is the [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) representation of `12345`.

`39 30 00 00` are 4 bytes which is the typical size for an `int`.

Note that this number is not `0x39300000` but `0x00003039`.

The byte order of the number written is dependent on the endianness of your system.

You can observe this yourself, by using [`htonl`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl) to convert from host endianness to big-endian (network byte order):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *ptr_myfile;
    char c = 'a';
    int numero = 12345;
    ptr_myfile = fopen("test.txt","w");

    if (!ptr_myfile) {
        printf("Unable to open file!");
        return 1;
    }

    // convert from host endianness to network byte order
    int numero_big_endian = htonl(numero);

    fwrite(&c, sizeof(char), 1, ptr_myfile);
    fwrite(&numero_big_endian, sizeof(int), 1, ptr_myfile);
    fclose(ptr_myfile);

    return 0;
}
```

This will yield:

```
$ hexdump -C test.txt

00000000  61 00 00 30 39                                    |a..09|
00000005
```

As you can see the byte order is now reversed.

This is one of the reasons why you might not want to write binary data directly to disk because of the differences in endianness.

A big-endian system will recognize `0x00003039` as `0x39300000` which would be `959447040` and not `1234`.

As others have mentioned, `fwrite` does not write data in their string representation.

If you want that, you can use `snprintf` (or use `fprintf`) to convert your number to a string first, then write it to a file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE *ptr_myfile;
    char c = 'a';
    int numero = 12345;
    ptr_myfile = fopen("test.txt","w");

    if (!ptr_myfile) {
        printf("Unable to open file!");
        return 1;
    }

    // convert numero to a string
    char numero_str[64];
    // check result of snprintf, omitted for readability
    snprintf(numero_str, sizeof(numero_str), "%d", numero);

    fwrite(&c, sizeof(char), 1, ptr_myfile);
    fwrite(numero_str, strlen(numero_str), 1, ptr_myfile);
    fclose(ptr_myfile);

    return 0;
}
```

```
$ cat test.txt

a12345
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use `fwrite` the write function processes data as if it is binary of a certain length. This has nothing to do with the file opening mode you selected earlier.

Lets consider the following example:

```
/** A character buffer. */
char *ascii_buf = "ABCD";

/** A buffer which contains binary representation of A, B, C, D letters in ASCII. */
uint8_t binary_buf[4] = { 65, 66, 67, 68 };

written = fwrite(ascii_buf, 1, strlen(ascii_buf), fout);
written = fwrite(binary_buf, 1, sizeof(binary_buf), fout);
```

The above two calls to `fwrite` result in the same output `"ABCD"` into the target output file.

The only difference resids in the way the data is interpreted. In the first case `ascii_buf` data is interpreted as character. While in the second case `binary_buf` data is interpreted as unsigned integers. There content is the same, but their representation is different.

You will usually want to use:

- `fprintf` to output formatted strings to a file.
- `fwrite` to output raw data to a file.